# include() a file so every function has access

Tags: php

if I do this

```
include('orderConst_pdo_connect.php');
switch  ($type){
    case "retrieve":
        retrieve_address($customer_id);
        break;
    case "new":
        new_address($customer_id, $address);
        break;
    case "update":
        update_address($customer_id, $address_id);
        break;
    case "delete":
        delete_address($customer_id, $address_id);
        break;              
}

function retrieve_address($customer_id){
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT * 
    FROM   address 
    WHERE  customer_id = :customer_id 
    ORDER  BY CASE 
                WHEN use_frequency IS NULL THEN id 
                ELSE use_frequency 
              END ASC");

.... 

}
```

I get the error

`Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`

until i put the `include('orderConst_pdo_connect.php')` inside the function. Is there a way to include the file  and give the function access to it at the top of the page, or do i need to include it in every function that uses it?

Comment: You should consider using a database abstraction layer to make this less painful. Doctrine is an example of one for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `global`, just do:

```
function retrieve_address($dbh, $customer_id) {
    // blah
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Variables defined within your include file, by default will not be available inside functions. You can grant your function access to this variable with `global $dbh`

Comment: Probably not this century.

Comment: I guess that's a matter of opinion. Depending on the size of your project you may want to consider an OOP approach. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: `global $dbh;
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$db_name; host=$host", $username, $password );` doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I went on the assumption that $dbh is instantiated within your include file. If so, simply: `global $dbh` at the top of your `retrieve_address` function

Comment: aha ... why do I need to declare `global $dbh` at the top of the function again? Thanks for the help!

Comment: See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for an explanation on function scope and `global`

Comment: Or, even better, you could simply pass $dbh into any function that needs it via that function's argument list.  There's no reason to use 'global'.  All it does is blow apart scope and obfuscate a function/method/class' functional requirements.  Seeing $dbh in your function signature will remind you/tell others that the database connection needs to be present for it to work.